# Depth of the call-stack

Tags: node.js, logging, stack

Is there a way to know the current depth of the call-stack in Node.js?

In Java, I did this:

```
int depth = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace().length;
```

Then I could use it for logging, like this:

```
myLogger.writeLogMessage(depth, message);
```

where "writeLogMessage" uses the depth parameter to create a nicely-formatted tree of method calls.

Now I want to do the same in Node.js, but I don't know, how to calculate the depth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error object has a getter named 'stack' which returns a String containing the stack trace. Example from the REPL:

```
> console.log(Error().stack)
Error
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at repl:1:14
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:754:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
```

You should be able to calculate the depth by counting the number of lines.